# LayoutParams dont update after switching fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have some code on an image click handler to move a "selected tick" image next to the image that was clicked. This code works fine but after I switch to a new fragment and back the image no longer moves.

I believe that the layout parameters to not update immediately on calling SetLayoutParams and that this happens somewhere down the line but I dont understand why this stops happening when the fragement is reloaded given that its the same code that is being called.

```
 public void Item_Click(View view){

        ImageView button = (ImageView) view;
        Selector = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("Selector_Connected, "id", this.getPackageName()));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)Selector.getLayoutParams(); //new                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, button.getId());
        Selector.setLayoutParams(lp);
        Selector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

}

A fragment is swapped by next / previous buttons

```
  bundle.putInt("answer",current_survey.get_question1() );
            QuestionOne Q1Frag = new QuestionOne();
            Q1Frag.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, Q1Frag).commit();
```

When the new fragment is loaded this too moves the selector based on the information passed into it.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionone, container, false);
    Selector = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Selector_Connected);

    int answer = getArguments().getInt("answer");


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)Selector.getLayoutParams(); // new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, button.getId());
    ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("Connected_" + i, "id", view.getContext       ().getPackageName()));

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, button.getId());
    Selector.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return view;
}
```

As mentioned, all of this code works fine until moving to a new fragment and moving back again, the code is still called but the selector never moves!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem before
just make a new instance of LayoutParams and set all the properties you have in the xml to it programmatically so for example

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and than

```
 Selector.setLayoutParams(params);
```

hope it helps